# Writing a time function that will clear a countdown and restart during a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, tic-tac-toe

I am now working on a tic-tac-toe game in jQuery that has a built-in-timer function. The reasoning behind this function is that a player has 10 seconds to pick a space on the board for their X or O before the timer runs out and they receive an alert message. I'm having trouble implementing it; I can get it to work when the game starts, but I have issues getting it to reset itself and reload once the player makes a selection.

Here is the main timer function. $('.#timer') is the element in my html file that will be holding the function.

```
var clockStart = 10;
var clockEnd;

var start = function() {
  clockEnd = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      if (clockStart === 0) {
        alert("You took too long to put in your answer! GAME OVER!");
        location.reload();
      }
  }

var countdown = function() {
  if (clockStart > 0) {
    clockStart = clockStart - 1;
    $('#timer').html(clockStart);
      }
}

alert("game instructions");
alert("It's Player 1's turn!");
start();
```

Now, what can I get the function to reset once the player clicks a space on the board? My game operates itself mainly through click elements. For example, here is the function that controls X and O.

```
$('.grid').on('click', function () {
  if ($(this).children().length === 0 ) {
    click += 1;
    if (click === 1) {
      $(this).html("X_img");
      $(this).addClass("xClass");
    }
    else if (click % 2 === 1 ) {
      $(this).html("<img src = 'X_img' />");
      $(this).addClass("xClass");
    }
    else {
      $(this).html("<img src = 'O_img' />");
      $(this).addClass("oClass");
    }
  }
  else {
    alert("That box already has an element in it!");
    }
  checkIfWon();
  checkIfDraw();
  })
```

Can anyone give any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `setInterval()` to run the countdown function every 1000 seconds. The point of setInterval() is to repeatedly run something on a schedule until specifically told to stop.

The way you tell setInterval to stop is by using it's partner `clearInterval()`. clearInterval takes the *intervalId* as an argument. The intervalId is returned by setInterval when it's run, in your case you've assigned it to the 'clockend' variable.

You may find these two pages useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the following function (or something similar would be the answer?
    var countdown = function() {
  if (clockStart > 0) {
    clockStart = clockStart - 1;
    $('#timer').html(clockStart);
      }
  else if ($('.grid')).on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(clockEnd);
    })
}

Comment: @Leia_Organa - That won't do what you want. jQuery's .on function doesn't work that way. You want to make sure that clockEnd is saved in a scope that can be accessed later. Preferable it's a member of an object, but you COULD give it global scope.  Then wherever you're handling the click event (making your X and Os) go ahead and clearInterval there. -- EDITED